# React-Ladda-Button : How to pass the properties into OnClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ladda

Seek help using React ladda button. the LaddaButton have a property call "loading" and i wanted to pass it into my onClick function so that i can enable\disable loading within my onClick function:

I am using React Ladda Button(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ladda-button?activeTab=readme).

```
 import LaddaButton  from 'react-ladda-button';

   <LaddaButton
        data-style={EXPAND_LEFT}
        className='btn btn-danger btn-sm'
        onClick={(e, b) => {
          myFunction(e, rowData);
        }}
      >
        Click Me
      </LaddaButton>


//My method
  const myFunction = async (e, item) => {

      //how to call the loading propery in LaddaButton from this methond?
     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually (from the code examples I have seen) a function called toggle is used to toggle Ladda Buttons on and off. But I have noticed when coding Ladda Buttons that they are unresponsive to clicks when loading. I have been able to change its loading state from not-loading to loading with a click but not vice-versa. Maybe instead you could use a timeout or change the state after a condition has been met etc. This is the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ladda) I have read for Ladda Buttons.

Please find my code below, it causes the Ladda Button to change state from not-loading to loading when clicked. But unfortunately it cannot change from loading to not-loading with a click.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import './index.css';
import './App.css';
import LaddaButton, { EXPAND_LEFT } from 'react-ladda';

class LaButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state =  { loading: false };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this)
  }
  toggle() {
      this.setState({
        loading: true,
        progress:0.5,
      }); 
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <LaddaButton
      data-style={EXPAND_LEFT}
      className='btn btn-danger btn-sm'
      loading={this.state.loading}
      onClick={this.toggle}
      >
        Click Here!
      </LaddaButton>
    );
  }
 };
 
 ReactDOM.render(<LaButton />, document.getElementById("root"));

reportWebVitals();
```